# Mapbox setCameraPosition not centering view correctly

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-gl

I'm  creating a Mapbox MapView and computing a LatLngBounds based on a list of several points. When I set the camera position the points are all contained in the view, but over to the right side, not centered, and the zoom level is not optimal. In the `onMapReady()` callback from `mapView.getMapAsync()` I collect a list of points in a `LatLngBounds.Builder` then do:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = llb.build();
CameraUpdate cam = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 20);
mapboxMap.setCameraPosition(cam.getCameraPosition(mapboxMap));
```

The result however is like this, whereas I am expecting the points to be centered in the view, and the zoom level to be the maximum possible with all the points showing plus padding.

[image]

Where the three markers are showing in their correct positions. I have verified in the debugger that the `CameraUpdate` value accurately represents the bounding box of the three points.
Is this a Mapbox bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a particular camera padding bug in the recent Mapbox SDKs (iOS v3.2.x and Android v4.0.x) that [will be fixed](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/4914) in the next major releases.

Try out the latest “snapshot” Android build and see if this issue still occurs (and let us know if it does).

Comment: Reducing the padding to zero does not fix it, so I don't think that particular bug is related. I have noticed that if the device orientation changes and the map is recreated (it's in a DialogFragment) then the problem disappears - it is only when first drawn that it happens. Is `onMapReady` the appropriate place to do this stuff?

Comment: I will try the latest snapshot though and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: Updated to 4.1.0-SNAPSHOT and it's working fine now.

Comment: I appreciate the response. My next problem - MarkerOptions has no anchor() method, nor is the default anchor position defined in the docs as far as I can see.